# How to call the value from circular slider in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, package, slider

I am just getting used to flutter and I used https://pub.dev/packages/sleek_circular_slider Circular slider package from flutter packages,
I have created my layout and given  `onChange`  command. Slider is working fine. Now, i want to use that slider value in my other methods... I tried using many things but it's just not working. pls let me now  how to call the value from slide and use it ?
 Also there is `innerWidget` parameter whose docs says to be doing the job but i don't know how to make it work????

Here is `

```
class WeightSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<WeightSlider> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(child: slider),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  final slider = SleekCircularSlider(
    min: 0,
    max: 120.0,
    initialValue: 60,
    appearance: CircularSliderAppearance(
        size:279,
        startAngle: 120,
        angleRange: 300,
        animationEnabled: true,
        infoProperties: InfoProperties(
          bottomLabelText: 'kg',
          bottomLabelStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 25,
          ),
          mainLabelStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 70,
            fontFamily: 'RalewaySemiBold',
          ),
          modifier: (double value) {
            final roundedValue = value.ceil().toInt().toString();
            return '$roundedValue ';
          },
        ),
        customColors: CustomSliderColors(
          hideShadow: true,
          trackColor: Color(0XFFFFF176),
          dotColor: Color(0XFFFAFAFA),
          progressBarColor: Color(0XFF00E676),
        ),
        customWidths: CustomSliderWidths(
          trackWidth: 5,
          progressBarWidth: 20,
          handlerSize: 4,
        )
    ),
    onChangeEnd: (double weight){
      return weight;
    },
  );

  }
```

` my code...

Comment: `it's just not working` please add more detail about what is not working.

Comment: actually it is a separate code for my design of slider...what i want is to get the output value of slider and use it on my other methods

Comment: You already have the value from `onChangeEnd`. Where is the problem?

Comment: i want to call this value into my other methods..how do i do that...i am basically making a bmi app, so now when user selects his/her value , i am going to put that value in my calculation class for further sloving

Comment: Take the value and store it as a class field? Pass it directly to these methods as an argument? I'm honestly not sure where the issue is.

Comment: can u show this through some code..pls i know how to do above...but it's just not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the value of the slider and update the UI as the value changes with the help of the provider class since you cannot use setState in the predefined methods of sleek circular slider.

1) You need to import [provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)

2) Then, update the value in the provider class

3) Use Consumer widget to listen to the changes and update the UI.

Sample Code:

Provider Class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProviderClassName with ChangeNotifier {
  int value = 0;

  void setValue(int newValue) {
    value = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

SleekCircularSlider

```
onChange: (double value) {
  Provider.of<ProviderClassName>(context, listen: false).setValue(value.floor().toInt());
  // callback providing a value while its being changed (with a pan gesture)
},
```

Where you want to use the value

```
Consumer<ProviderClassName>(
          builder: (context, providerClassName, child) => Text(
              '${providerClassName.getValue()}')
```

Answer (score -1):

Modifier attribute is called during build so you can't set the state. To obtain the final value (when user raises his finger) use onChangedEnd and onChange for each step.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sleek_circular_slider/sleek_circular_slider.dart';

class WeightSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<WeightSlider> {
  double myValue;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myValue = 0;
  }

  otherMethod(String rounded) {
    print("rounded: " + rounded);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final slider = SleekCircularSlider(
      min: 0,
      max: 120.0,
      initialValue: 60,
      appearance: CircularSliderAppearance(
          size: 279,
          startAngle: 120,
          angleRange: 300,
          animationEnabled: true,
          infoProperties: InfoProperties(
            bottomLabelText: 'kg',
            bottomLabelStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 25,
            ),
            mainLabelStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 70,
              fontFamily: 'RalewaySemiBold',
            ),
          ),
          customColors: CustomSliderColors(
            hideShadow: true,
            trackColor: Color(0XFFFFF176),
            dotColor: Color(0XFFFAFAFA),
            progressBarColor: Color(0XFF00E676),
          ),
          customWidths: CustomSliderWidths(
            trackWidth: 5,
            progressBarWidth: 20,
            handlerSize: 4,
          )),
      innerWidget: (double value) {
        // use your custom widget inside the slider (gets a slider value from the callback)
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Slider(
                value: value,
                min: 0,
                max: 120,

                onChanged: (double weight) {
                  setState(() {
                    String newValue = weight.ceil().toInt().toString();
                    print("$newValue");
                    otherMethod(newValue);
                  });
                }),
             Container(
                    color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                    child: Text(
                      "Test text $value",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ))
          ],
        );
      },
      onChangeEnd: (double weight) {
        setState(() {
          String newValue = weight.ceil().toInt().toString();
          print("$newValue");
          otherMethod(newValue);
        });
      },
    );
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(child: slider),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Not working...It has `innerWidget` parameter whose docs say 'A custom widget to replace the build in text labels which can capture a slider value from the callback.'... can anyone make use of that ?????

Comment: It was working, but if you want innerWidget ok, here you have it. Hope you like it.

Comment: putting // does not show people what to put their,, i asked you WHAT to put their,, in simple words,,, give example of the content b/w `innerWidget`